Translucent background for fullScreenCover custom menu
I need to make a transparent background when a menu opens. I press the button menu and I need to see a centre screen component with three menu items to choose and transparent background.
This is my Menu code snippet:
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone ? 12 : 24)
                                .inset(by: 0.5)
                                .stroke(Color(red: 0.25, green: 0.41, blue: 1), lineWidth: 2)
                        )
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.8, height: geo.size.height * 0.3)
                        .padding()
                    Spacer()
                }
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    makeMenuItems(with: geo, menuItem: .map)
                    makeMenuItems(with: geo, menuItem: .locations)
                    makeMenuItems(with: geo, menuItem: .settings)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}

This is menu button in other screens which call menu:
private func makeMenuButton() -> some View {
    Button {
        isMenuPresented.toggle()
    } label: {
        Image(menuIcon)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 24)
    }
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isMenuPresented) {
        ZStack {
            Menu_VW(item: .locations)
        }
    }
}

I need it to be like this:

Now I have this:


There is a function, named presentationBackground(_:) that may meet your expectation:
private func makeMenuButton() -> some View {
    ...
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isMenuPresented) {
        ZStack {
            Menu_VW(item: .locations)
        }
        .presentationBackground(.black.opacity(0.5)) //<- here
    }
}

Update: Since you need to support iOS below 16.4, this solution can help. Since NavigationView was deprecated, you may consider using NavigationStack instead.
struct TransparentBackgroundView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            view.superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5) //<- this line do the trick
        }
        return view
    }
}

Then you need to apply on both NavigationView and the nested ZStack within your MenuView:
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                ...
            }
            .background(TransparentBackgroundView()) //<- here
        }
    }
    .background(TransparentBackgroundView()) //<- here
}


No, it’s in iOS 16.4 and higher. I need to support from iOS 15

I updated the answer, you can take a look.
